# How to import h3-py (uber) on windows after installing it?

Tags: data-visualization, uber-api, h3

I want to ask about h3-py installation on windows

I have tried to install h3 on windows with python 
I ran the command pip install h3 and it is installed.

After install, when I try to import it, i get this error:

```
    from h3 import h3
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h3\h3.py", line 39, in <module>
    libh3 = cdll.LoadLibrary('{}/{}'.format(_dirname, libh3_path))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're in the process of migrating the wrapper to Cython at https://github.com/uber/h3-py/tree/cython

Would you mind trying to install this cython version with these (temporary) install steps:

```
pip install scikit-build
pip install git+https://github.com/uber/h3-py.git@cython
```

Edit:

We've released `3.6.1` along with pre-built wheels on PyPI and conda. Install should now be as simple as

```
pip install h3
```

Answer (score 0):

Apprently there was a problem with the package and after fixing it in the release v3.6.1 it works. they fixed install issues. 
As mentioned in this issue on github : 
https://github.com/uber/h3-py/issues/32